# how to fit polygon inside another polygon

Tags: algorithm

I have two polygons as shown in the image below.
The left one is "rough polygon" and the right one is "final polygon"

[image: Polygon]

Now, I'm looking for algorithm to fit "final polygon" inside "rough polygon" with best maximum ***scale***.

- you can ***rotate*** as well as ***translate*** "final polygon" as much as you want.
- you can't perform individual **x dimension** or **y dimension** scaling.
- you can only perform uniform scaling (where value of **Sx** and **Sy** are same).

Comment: Are the polygons convex?

Comment: @cerkiewny You can see for yourself, that they are not necessarily.

Comment: Sounds like a packing problem of sorts... Have you looked into algorithms for packing irregular shapes? It's probably related and you might get some inspiration, ie. approximating the shapes as being composed of smaller squares to simplify the problem. I imagine though that this problem is not deterministic, so you're probably going to have to search for a solution which is "good enough" rather than the true solution.

Comment: @user1095108 there is no image therefore i am asking

Comment: You might find this to be of some relevance or relation, though it's not exactly what you're looking for: http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/hicss/2003/1874/03/187430086.pdf

Comment: @cerkiewny I see an image.. o.o Bizarre.

Comment: @kotakotakota I see just a '.' in place where image should be... probably some company restrictions in my office. Oh well.

Comment: @cerkiewny hahaha pr0n polygon...

Comment: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/PolygContainmentProb.pdf

Comment: @kotakotakota I've made some steps to get possibly best solution. that're 1). put final polygon on the center of rough polygon. 2). now, scale it upto the limit when it collide with border of rough polygon. 3). now, at maximum scaling, rotate final polygon so, we might get more scaling.

Comment: @kotakotakota your suggestion of small squares is also good. this will might help me. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck :) Also, be sure to look into the link @firda gave. There is a whole class of problems (polygon containment) which your problem is a variation of.

Comment: @firda Thanks for your link. hope this might help me!

Comment: I am afraid that this is a very difficult problem, for which you won't even find theoretical solutions in the literature !

Comment: @Yves Daoust yes, you're right! but, there is nothing impossible. i might not found best solution but, I'll surely find working solution.

Comment: First solve this for two arbitrary triangles !

Comment: This looks like an optimization problem and you might be able to solve it using linear programming. [Here's](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ga/slides4.pdf) a similar problem ( finding a direction of removal from a cast mold ) that was done with linear programming

Comment: @Arun R this is something for what I'm looking for... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible line of attack for an exact solution by exhaustive trials; just ideas.

My guess is that a solution is achieved when there are three contacts. I mean three vertexes of either polygon touching an edge of the other or conversely. (If there are less than three contacts, you can inflate the internal polygon so that it comes into a third contact.)

Given two arbitrary triangles, it shouldn't be so difficult to find all possible three-contact positions.

So the global scheme is to take all triples of vertexes/sides from one polygon, and take all complementary triples of sides/vertexes of the other. For every combination, momentarily consider that you have triangles and find the possible three-contact positions. For for every candidate position check if the inner polygon stays confined in the outer one. In the end, keep the admissible solution with the largest scale factor.

For polygons with `N` and `M` sides, there will be `O(N³M³)` configurations to try, and the containment test can be as costly as `O(NM)`. So this approach is only viable for very small polygons.

Comment: This initial sketch is probably wrong in details, but you get the general idea: find how many contact constraints do define an extremal solution, and what type they can be (among vertex/side, side/vertex, vertex/vertex or side/side). Then try all combinations generating that number of contacts, find the corresponding extremal configurations, and check if they are admissible.

Answer (score -1):

Scale the rightside polygon by 0.01. (geometrical)

Start spinnning it so fast that it draws circle. (geometrical)

Start incrementing the scale 0.01 by 0.01. (geometrical)

Stop when it touches the outer polygon. (geometrical)

Then bounce it to opposite direction until it bounces again. (physical)

Again and again.(iterations)

Until it cannot move/bounce again.(stuck optimally) (physical)

Use simulated annealing in case of false local solutions.(you need global solution)

Comment: Haha, start spinning it so fast, that your hands start hurting.

Comment: Basically you are suggesting an unintelligent, potentially innacurate, brute force method of finding by attempt and failure the answer. I don't think thats what OP is looking for. Besides, what guarantees that the first time it collides it will be in optimal angle to expand?

Comment: what about releasing a polygon from a height then let it fall on top of other polygon. Trying for 1000 times and getting the best fit? (with just different scaling, physics handle other variations automatically )