# What algorithms can I use to check if a polygon fits inside of another polygon?

Tags: python, math, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

I'm trying to write a program in which I have a "master" polygon, and I want to check whether other polygons can fit inside of it.

These polygons are of arbitrary shape/size, are often convex, and cannot self-intersect.

Basically, given two polygons `A` and `B`, I want to find the translation (rotating/moving) of polygon `A` that makes it "best" fit inside of polygon `B`.

If `A` fits entirely within `B`, the "best" fit is the configuration that maximizes the distance between the closest two points on both polygons.

If `A` does not fit entirely within `B`, the "best" fit is the configuration that minimizes the area of the parts of `A` that are not covered by `B`.

Is there a fast algorithm that can do this? If this is very complicated, I'd prefer something already implemented, perhaps in CGAL.

Comment: IMO, what you are asking is so difficult that nobody ever tackled it. Just checking if a polygon can fit inside another, with rotation and translation, is a little nightmare.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182546/how-to-fit-polygon-inside-another-polygon